# View of groups available to join

Tags: 8, users, group

My site has different types of groups. Some allow registered users to join, others are by invite only and the existence of the group is not publicised.

I want to make a view (or block) of groups that a user is able to join, (i.e. group permissions for outsider: can "join group").

Groups that are secret, or groups that the user has already joined, should not appear in the view.

Is this possible through views contextual filters/relationships? If so, how?